# Hirsch chumash online

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, samson-raphael-hirsch

Is there a Samson Raphael Hirsch pirush on chumash available online?

Preferably an English version and preferably something easy to copy and paste off of.

There are times I would like to post something on this site that he writes in his pirush, and it would be much easier to just copy and paste.

Comment: Are you looking for a particular format? E.g. it must be text, it can be an OCRed document? A particular language? A particular translation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

R' Hirsch's commentary [is available](http://nleresources.com/2018/11/new-free-hebrew-translation-of-rabbi-s-r-hirschs-torah-commentary-online/) in Hebrew translation as one of the commentaries in [AlHatorah.org's Mikraot Gedolot](http://mg.alhatorah.org/).

You can jump straight to his commentary on a particular verse using a URL of the form

> `http://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/R._S.R._Hirsch/BBB/C.V`

where

- BBB is the name of the book - Bereshit, Shemot, Vayikra, Bemidbar, or Devarim
- C is the chapter number
- V is the verse number

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks. That URL form isn't really working for me, but this is great. Is this the standard Hebrew Hirsch?

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://sammlungen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/judaica/search/quick?query=Hirsch%2C+Samson+Raphael) you will find his most important works, but only in German:

Until now I did not find any translation in English which is available online.

Comment: +1 thanks for this. I was going to add preferably in English, but that would have been meant as apposed to hebrew. This came as a surprise to me:) But thanks again.

Comment: German is the original. Both English and Hebrew are translations.

Comment: Try using Google Translate.

Comment: @LN6595 I am aware German is the original. I didn't expect anyone to suggest it. An oversight on my part. If you are suggesting Google translate, I'll assume you don't use it much for anything too important.

Answer (score 2):

The Feldheim (1948) English introduction to Genesis Vol. I from Creation to the Death of Avrohom, can be found [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/4105) and  [here](https://web.stevens.edu/golem/llevine/rsrh/intro_rsrh_torah_1.pdf).

It is copy-pastable, but far from perfectly.