# What are the best (english) texts for wordplay in commentaries? Ie, concordance. Also, that include mystical interpretations from multiple Rabbis?

Tags: talmud-gemara, tanach, mysticism-kabbalah, arizal

In Tanakh specific to the first levels of pardes, every word has a meaning, and many Rabbinic teachings in "oral Torah" associated with those meanings. However, with Kabbalistic interpretations, not only does each word have its own literal meaning, but there are innumerable wordplays and numeric equivalences used to connect one teaching with a seemingly unrelated other teaching, or create new teachings. No matter how much I read, I continue to come across new terms and wordplays. The possibilities for equivalences of terms in the Torah is endless, even more so than spoken languages like english, which must be why I feel the need to look for a "dictionary" of sorts more so than I do with language.

My first question is, are there any good references in english where you can look up a word and find out every other word that the Rabbis equated with that word through various "equations" and the associated teachings? A concordance of Kabbalistic terms. I don't mean "Malkut is the 10th sefirah" I mean like every time AriZal defines or interprets a term from a verse in Tanakh, or makes a kabbalistic equation with another term.

My second question is similar, but for verses. Are there any english references where I can look up a verse from Tanakh, and all organized in one chapter it will tell me the Rebbe's commentary and major teachings about it, Rashi's, Rambam's, Ramban's, AriZal's, Vilna Gaon's, Nachmanides, Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai's, all the other giants of the generations?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Your second question appears to be whether there is an English translation of Mikraot Gedolot. That was partially addressed here:  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52988/where-can-i-get-english-commentaries-on-the-nach and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77853/hirsch-chumash-online/111220#111220

Comment: And of course online you have https://www.sefaria.org/texts and https://alhatorah.org/

Comment: Thanks so much @mbloch. I joined this forum because I've been a lurker for awhile and I've seen so many great answers here. So I really appreciate the warm welcome. As for Mikraot Gedolot, I was actually not familiar with that title, but it's great it is in English. What I was asking for was a text where you can look up the opinions of all the Rabbinic authorities, including the kabbalists, on any question, any verse, any term.

Comment: @mbloch For example, I dont want to find out for the 1st time after 20 yrs of reading that "the word for .. "defect" ["pagam"] is .. 3 times the # of letters in .. Eh‑yeh," which corresponds to judgments. I am looking for a text where I can look up a word and it will immediately tell me, "the Ari taught that this related to Eh-yeh," "Ramban taught that it related to.." and so on. 

Likewise with Tanakh. I want to look up a verse, and not just see this is what Rashi said, this is what Ari said, but rather, see what they all said side by side, and what the agreements and disagreements were.

Comment: Is there a way to reply or tag people? Using @ doesn't seem to do anything. Also how to vote the comments?

Comment: Basically I am looking for two books:

1. A concordance of kabbalistic terms and definitions. Not "Malkut: This is the 10th sefirot," but instead, "Malkut: Here is a list of every single term used to refer to Malkut, organized by the various kabbalists who used the terms". And so on. It should be a list of hundreds or thousands of words. And the same thing for every word in Tanakh.

2. A text where you can look up a verse and find the opinions, agreements, and disagreements of all the Rabbinic authorities.

Also I ran out of chars but "pagam" was just random example, first I could find.

Comment: The @ works, and I am getting pinged when you use it with my name. Mikraot Gedolot is the name of a book (different editions exist) that has all classical commentaries for all verses in the Torah/Tanakh. It doesn't include kabalistic writers except for Ramban. As I wrote Sefaria and AlHatorah also do this very well online and for free. On your first question, I don't have the knowledge

Comment: @mbloch Thank you. What Sefaria is doing is great but right now every time I go there, the majority of the time there is no english translation for what I look up. I don't know if AlHatorah is different. These are libraries of texts but which text do I read in the library that has all the commentaries? Maybe we could start with, what are the names of the commentaries written by each Rabbi? Especially the Kabbalists. Then once I know the names, I can see if any are in english. But a text that summarizes all the kabbalist views and disagreements, and tells which is the final "ruling," would help

Comment: @mbloch Basically if you want to know which literal interpretation and halacha to follow, you can study the halachah, but where does one find out which Kabbalist or deeper interpretations are the ones to go by? I think Elliot Wolfson has a scholary text about Kabblah and law but I think he is a professor not a Rabbi, although I could be mistaken.

Comment: The above should say "ethics" not only law. I am not only interested in the kabbalah of the 613 commandments, but the ethics and "takeaways" of the different interpretations overall. There are many kabbalists, some had (on the surface) conflicting interpretations, so Im wondering if there is a text that summaries those and reconciles them, so that you can apply it to your life rather than being frozen between "is it this way or that way?"

Comment: There is no reconciliation of kabbalistic opinions, nor much translated authentic Kabala in English. Reason is that learning Kabala can only come after many years of learning of more traditional Torah and Halakha. You might want to find a local rabbi to study with, he will help you get into the topics that interest you